# type predicate-ness lost when using Function.prototype.bind

Tags: typescript, types

this errors for me with TS 3.2.4:

```
const isArray: typeof Array.isArray = Array.isArray.bind(Array);
```

The error is

```
error TS2322: Type '(arg: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg: any) => arg is any[]'.
  Signature '(arg: any): boolean' must be a type predicate.
```

What seems to be happening is that the type predicate-ness of Array.isArray is lost when .bind is used. I tested with a few type predicate functions, and always get the same error.

**Is this a for-real TS bug, or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Yes; this is a real bug.

Comment: is it reported? I'm afraid of making a dupe

Comment: @MaxHeiber I can't find a bug, I tried searching for `type guard strict Bind` and `type guard strictBindCallApply` but nothing relevant came up. I don't believe the type system can model this in a non 'lets have 1000 overloads' way, but you might want an oficial position on that :)

Answer (score 2):

Not so much a bug, rather a design limitation. The way Typescript does `strictBindCallApply` is by having several overloads of `bind` that work with different number of parameters:

```
bind<T, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T): (...args: A) => R;
bind<T, A0, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0): (...args: A) => R;
bind<T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): (...args: A) => R;
bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): (...args: A) => R;
bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
bind<T, AX, R>(this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
```

The problem with this approach is that a type guard function, returns a simple `boolean` which will be captured by `R` and forwarded to the return type. But the guard behavior is not captured or forwarded in `R`. It is just erased.

While it is possible to write a `bind` function that takes into account the type guard behavior it is hard to get a version that works for all possible permutations.

For example, this would work for your case:

```
declare function bind<T, A0, A extends any[], R>(fn: (this: T, arg0: A0 | R, ...args: A) => arg0 is R, thisArg: T): (arg0: A0 | R, ...args: A) => arg0 is R;
const isArray: typeof Array.isArray = bind(Array.isArray, Array);
```

But this assumes the guarded argument is the first one, there is nothing preventing you from having 10 parameters with you guarding the last one. To catch such a case you would need to have an overload with `arg0...arg9` (and also all overloads in between).

I will search for an issue, but my  guess is that the type system just can't model this in an eficient way, and crowding the overloads with type-guard versions was just not worth it for this corner use case.

**Edit** Can't find a bug on GitHub, you could post one to get an official opinion on the matter and not just a guy on SO opinion :)

Comment: thanks for checking and explaining, I made on issue on TS repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29531

Comment: apparently it's a real issue, but Wesley on TS team thinks it can be fixed with overloads and marked the issue "Help Wanted". Your comments suggest there would be a lot of overloads, but I suppose it's doable. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29531

Comment: @MaxHeiber yes I saw the issue. I saw the issue, I agree with him, a couple of oveloads for common cases should do the trick :)